# Источник данных для Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ui

Привет есть код.
Я пытаюсь задать источник для UI auticomplete

```
    public ActionResult Index(string term)
            {
                List<dynamic> lst;
                using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Url.Content(Server.MapPath(@"Data/data.json"))))
                {
                    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(json);
                }
                var Items=lst.Where(item=>item.IndexOf(term,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);

                return Json(Items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
Но не выходит!! Пишет что нет определения для IndexOf


UPD!!!

Решил поробывать вот так
public JsonResult Search(string term)
        {
            List<dataJson> lst = new List<dataJson>();
            lst.Add(new dataJson { Id = 1, City = "Москва" });
            lst.Add(new dataJson { Id = 2, City = "Мокварич" });
            lst.Add(new dataJson { Id = 3, City = "Могилево" });
            lst.Add(new dataJson { Id = 4, City = "Москвцц" });
            lst.Add(new dataJson { Id = 5, City = "Москцвцва" });
            lst.Add(new dataJson { Id = 6, City = "Москвцвцва" });
            var CityName = (from item in lst where item.City.Contains(term) select new { item.City });

            return Json(CityName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Все вроде ОК  и если начать вводить то возвращает и открывается список но он пустой хотя подсказка пишет что найдено 4 соответствий.
Не пойму почему список пустой

Comment: автор покажите js-код

Comment: А Вы уверены что `item` у Вас всегда строка?

Comment: `$(function () {
            $("#list").autocomplete({
                source: @Url.Action("Index")
                //minLength: 0
            });//.focus(function () {
                //$(this).autocomplete("search");
               // });
        });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась получение данных через функцию js

```
(document).ready(function () {
            $("#list, #list1").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Home/AutoCompleteCountry",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {term: request.term},
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.City, value: item.City };
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                },
                minLength: 2
            }).focus(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
            });
        })
```

Это конечно не то что хочется.Хотелось бы обойтись без js и сразу передавать строку в контроллер и от туда получать ответ